# Does SPList.ItemCount equal SPList.Folders.Count plus SPList.Items.Count?

Tags: 2007, splistitem, splist

I'm trying to do some inventorying of SharePoint 2007 content and have been scratching my head over this for a while now.

I understand from MSDN that `SPList.ItemCount` counts all folders and items together, while `SPList.Items.Count` counts just the `SPListItem` objects which are not folders.

However, I have some `SPList`s where the count is inconsistent.  In my example, `SPList.ItemCount` is **392** and `SPList.Items.Count` is **343**.  This implies to me that `SPList.Folders.Count` is **49**, but, in reality, it is **51**.  Using explorer mode, I have enumerated all of the folders and subfolders and confirmed there are **51** of them.  (Incidentally, I also counted the number of files, which were indeed **343**.)

So, the question is, why does `SPList.ItemCount` give an incorrect count?  Is there a way I can reconcile `ItemCount` and `SPList.Folders.Count` and `SPList.Items.Count`?

Edit:  After considering the answers, I'm just going to take `SPList.ItemCount` as a ballpark estimate instead of a stringent count.  Thanks everyone for the consideration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemCount and Items.Count are different in the way they treat SPFolders . If you see in reflector , SPList.Items returns the list items by running a query with Scope=Recursive ViewAttribute.

Also , the SPList.ItemCount is the efficient and recommended way to retrieve items count in a list.

PS the link , i suppose the issue is resolved in sharepoint 2010 : http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/negative-item-count-in-document-libraries/

Also check permissions  -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823338/why-cant-i-access-the-items-in-a-list-even-if-the-splist-itemcount-is-0

UPDATE:
Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923899/how-to-find-item-count-in-a-spfolder

Comment: Thanks for the links.  However, it's reporting the number of items and folders correctly.  The issue is that `SPList.ItemCount` is not totaling to the correct number.   `SPList.Items.Count` (although inefficient) reports 343 items (which I've verified by counting by hand) and `SPList.Folders.Count` reports 51 folders (which I've also verified by counting by hand).  I'm trying to figure out why `SPList.ItemCount` is reporting 392, which is 2 less than the item count and folder count.

Comment: Try list.update() once and then check .

Comment: Working in PowerShell, I've done this, disposed and reinstantiated the entire `SPWeb` object, and refreshed the `SPList` item.  Still the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into it with SharePoint Manager?
http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762

Comment: I've used SharePoint manager before, but I'm using PowerShell in order to look into the farm

Answer (score 0):

itemcount

- it is the "best practice"
- it contains folders
- it contains items in recycle bin, checked out items, etc
- may not always be up-to-date

items.count

- it is effectively counting the current list items
- it excludes folders
- it is security trimmed, so each user may get different results

given this, perhaps your discrepancy is due to deleted items, checked out items, or permission levels

references

http://www.1stquad.com/sharepoint-kompetenz-erfahrung-know-how/Blog/default/November-2012/SPList-ItemCount-not-same-as-SPList-Items-Count

http://www.spdev.info/2012/04/splistitemcount-vs-splistitemscount.html

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I'm looking for the reason why `SPList.ItemCount` is less than `SPList.Folders.Count` plus `SPList.Items.Count` (or, alternatively, the number of items I've counted by hand).  The discrepancy is with `SPList.ItemCount`, not `SPList.Items.Count`.

Comment: perhaps if you try making a few exports into a text/csv file you will easily identify those 2 extra/missing items

Answer (score 0):

First I'd check if the SPLists exposing this behaviour are any kind of special, like a DocLib, Picture Lib, Publishing Pages, or have Content Types, versioning or checkin/checkout enabled.

Also, as already mentioned, check if item level security is applied and in case of a DocLib if there are items which have no major/checked-in version.

There might be a problem with documents without a major version and it can be checked on the DocLib settings itself with an option for all items without a major version published.

Beside of that, there could be a hidden folder which might be visible in Explorer View if you have turned on the Windows File Explorer setting to display hidden files & folders.

In particular DocLibs have a hidden folder named `Forms` which I'm not sure if it is counted or not.